# Table Layout separation

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

In my application I am showing one table layout as shown in this image:

[image: Output]

This is my output. In that row is divied ,now I want is to have a vertical division in to 2 halves. Is it possible to have in table layout? Help me please. Thanks in advance.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="2dip"
    android:stretchColumns="4" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Income" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Expense" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse"
        android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text42"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text43"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text45"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text46"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text47"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text48"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text49"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="40px" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Total:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totincome"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="total" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Total:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totexpense"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="total:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_marginTop="40px" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:text="Balance:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp"
            android:text="balance" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain your requirement in more detail

Comment: i already mentioned in our chat session. please have a look. add a rightMargin as you need

Comment: do you need a separation like this ? http://i.imgur.com/acTgV.png

Comment: sunil this is what exactly what i need sunil..Also make sure that column vales are right aligned.In the image u posted column1 values are not right aligned..

Comment: hi sunil gud mor..r u there??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this new layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Income" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Expense" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text40"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text41"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/houseexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Household:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text42"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text43"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trlexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Travel:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text44"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduinctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text45"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eduexptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Education:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text46"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text47"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group4:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp4exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group4:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text48"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5inctot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#FF909090" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text49"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Group5:" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grp5exptot"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="group5:" >
        </TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF909090"
            android:padding="2dip" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

this is what i got while testing this
[image: table screenshot]